# Python class, have different value when called by print or format than when assigned to value

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I have a class that represents a point that I am using to replace tuples. With tuples I can just call `x, y = point` How can I emulate this functionality with a class? I can have `__repr__` return a tuple but it throws `TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type tuple)` if I try to call print. How is this functionality handled for tuples?

Comment: Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This seems very confused. `x, y = some_object` is unpacking and requires an iterable type. It has nothing to do with `__repr__` or printing.

Comment: You could let your `Point` class inherit from `tuple` or `list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want instances of your class to be usable like tuples on the right side of a multiple assignment statement like `x, y = some_object`, you need to make your class iterable. That behavior has nothing to do with the `__repr__` of your class.

Try something like this (with whatever additional methods you need):

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({}, {})".format(type(self).__name__, self.x, self.y)
```

Instances of this class are iterable, which means that an unpacking will work. They can also be printed, or turned into strings with `str` or `repr`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use your own class, use a `collections.namedtuple` instead?
The `help(collections.namedtuple)` even is an example about a Point type

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking is essentially iterating. Here is a sketch of how you could implement this in a `Point` class:

```
>>> class Point:
...     def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
...         self._values = (x, y)
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return iter(self._values)
...
>>> p = Point(1,2)
>>> a,b = p
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>>
```

Edit, of course, here I just wrap a tuple, but you can unpack anything that implements the [iterator protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301253/what-exactly-is-pythons-iterator-protocol).