# misunderstanding about Range in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, primes

I've been doing some exercises, and having one question for you guys.
following to the picture I added.
for `number =2` the range we get in the second line is from `2` until `2`.

so, why dont i get some error message? How does it work?

How does the program know to skip it and return `True`?

Code:

```
def main(number):
    for i in range(2,int(number**0.5)+1):
        if number % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
print main(2)
```

Thanks!!
[image: code example]

Comment: Not again... do **not** submit **pictures** of your code. Post the **actual code**.

Comment: To answer your question: because Python considers this an *empty* range. So it simply does not enumerate. Why do you want an error message?

Comment: OK, you are right about the code. I'd expect an error because I am talking about an I which does not exist. So what actually happens beyond the scene? What code lines do run? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some people think that Python attaches some special syntax between `for` and `range`, but `range` is an **object that supports iteration**.

This means that it has an `__iter__` function that returns an iterator, and this supports the [**iterator protocol**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301253/what-exactly-is-pythons-iterator-protocol). This is a protocol that allows us to enumerate items out of that object. Like we can also enumerate over a list, tuple, set, etc.

`for` on the other hand simply uses this protocol such that for each iteration, it aims to fetch the next element out of the iterator. In case there is a next element, it assigns that element to the variable(s) on the left side. In case the iterator is exhausted (has no elements anymore), it stops.

In case you construct a `range(start,stop)` object where `stop <= start`. That range object is considered to be *empty*: it simply does not enumerate any items. `for` does *not* know what it is enumerating, but since the iterator over the `range(..)` element simply says that there are no elements anymore `for` stops.

You might indeed argue that it would be better if `range(..)` raises an error in case the `stop` is less than or equal to `start`. But usually it is **wanted behavior** that no error is risen, and the loop simply does not execute.

You can compare `for i in range(0,n)` to a construct in the Java/C++ language family:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //...
}
```

In this case if `n` is less than or equal to zero, the loop will not be executed either. The `range(..)` object somewhat a generator for such type of loops.

A extra note is that `range` actually is more sophisticated than described here in this answer, since you can also add a `step`, and you can countdown. But this has no impact on the semantics of this answer.

You can make the code more elegant, by using a generator in an `all` statement. Like:

```
def main(number):
    return all(number % i for i in range(2,int(number**0.5)+1))
```

Furthermore we can boost performance a bit, by only checking *odd* divisors (and 2):

```
def main(number):
    sq = int(number ** 0.5) + 1
    return (number & 1) and all(number % i for i in range(3, n, 2))
```

Comment: Wow man! Thank you so much. What a great answer! Much appreciated! Thank you so much