# Convert from for-loop and while-loop to while-loop and while loop Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
for x in range(0,len(b)):
    if x+1 < len(b):
        if b[x][1] == 'B' and b[x+1][1] == 'B':
            a.append([b[x][0], b[x][2]])
        elif b[x][1] == 'B'and b[x+1][1] == 'I':
            kata = b[x][0]
            a = 1
            while True:
                if x+a < len(b):
                    if b[x+a][1] == 'I':
                        kata += ' ' + b[x+a][0]
                        a += 1
                    elif b[x+a][1] == 'B':
                        break
                else:
                    break
            a.append([kata, b[x][2]])
    else:
        if b[x][1] == 'B':
            a.append([b[x][0], b[x][2]])
```

Can someone help me to convert the for-loop become while-loop? and the while-loop stay while-loop?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to want to do that? A `while` loop offers no advantages here. If this is purely for exercise, see my answer below.

Comment: Maybe you should convert the `while` loop into a `for` loop: `for y in range(x+1, len(b)):` where `y = x+a`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `for` loop of the form

```
for x in y:
    #code
```

can always be turned into a `while` loop of the form

```
i=0
while i < len(y):
    x = y[i]        
    #code
    i += 1
```

since `x` in your case is just iterating through values `0` to `len(b)` you can further reduce it down to:

```
x=0
while x < len(b):       
    #code
    x += 1
```

Comment: This isn't *strictly* true – it won't work for generators, for instance. For that you would need to get an iterator over y via `it = y.__iter__()`, then do `try: x = it.next()` and catch `StopIteration`, per the [iterator protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301581/5951320).