# Fibonacci sequence in python using generator

Tags: python

```
def fibonacci_sequence():
    a,b = 1,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b

for i in range(10):
    print(fibonacci_sequence().__next__())
```

I tried using this in Python 3 to print out the fibonacci series. But the program just ends up printing 1 over and over again

Comment: Because you keep creating a new generator object, `fibonnacci_sequence()` and then you call `__next__()` on that new object, so of course, you only ever get the first value. As an aside, the **whole point** of generators is that you can iterate directly over them (they are iterators). Note also, you shouldn't call dunder methods directly, so if you *do* need it, use `next(some_iterator)` not `some_iterator.__next__()`

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring on each iteration a new generator you need to create one outside of the loop.

```
def fibonacci_sequence():
    a,b = 1,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b

generator = fibonacci_sequence()
for i in range(10):
    print(generator.__next__())
```

You could also use `next()`

```
generator = fibonacci_sequence()
for i in range(10):
    print(next(generator))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing the `fibonacci_sequence` each time in loop, do it like this:

```
def fibonacci_sequence():
    a,b = 1,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b

f = fibonacci_sequence()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

As said already, you need to instantiate the generator once only, outside the loop.

Also, avoid calling `__next__` directly, use `next(generator/iterator)` instead.

Having said that, in this simple case just let the `for` instruction handle the [iteration protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301253/what-exactly-is-pythons-iterator-protocol) (i.e. call `iter`, call `next` and catch the `StopIteration` exception).

We can also write the loop as:

```
import itertools as it

def fibonacci_sequence():
    a,b = 1,1
    while True:
        yield a
        a,b = b, a+b

for k in it.islice(fibonacci_sequence(),10):
    print(k)
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I modify this to print just the 10th Fibonacci number?

Comment: [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) allows to define the slice in several ways, exactly like you would with indexes. For example we can pass it where to start and end: `it.islice(fibonacci_sequence(),9,10)`