# How add index to the array with oprator input python?

Tags: python, typeerror

This the source  code:

```
 while (1):
     num =input("please enter for array  or  for lunch index array enter\"lunch\"")
     hh=[]
     p=int(len(hh))
     print(p)
     print(type(p))
    
     if(num=="lunch"):
      print(hh)
     elif(num=="end"):
      break
     else:
       cc=0
       for cc in p :
        hh.append(i,num)
        cc+=1
     print(hh)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python project\array.py", line 14, in <module>
    for cc in p :
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Why am I getting a TypeError?
And please explain what is a iterable...

Comment: You're trying to iterate over an integer - what's not clear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration

Answer (score 0):

Iterables are objects that have multiple items and support [iteration protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301253/what-exactly-is-pythons-iterator-protocol)
So lists, tuples, strings are iterable and integers are not